# Hide cell border in HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, cell

I want to remove cell border of HTML table, but keep "outside" border.

Such a default HTML table will be created like this:

[image]

But I want a layout like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css to achieve that. Please have  look on the below code

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="border" >
<thead>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-head">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="border-head">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="border-head" >&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and use css like

```
<style>
 .border {
   border:solid 1px #000;
 }
.border-head {
 border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
 }
</style>
```

you can see the action in js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/azeezkallayi/98t86Lrk/)

Answer (score 1):

Only way is via css.
Reset all border to 0 px and then with different class you can override it and show only the desired borders on the specific cell

```
table {
border: 0px;
}
.bottom {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
border-left: 1px solid black
}
....
```

And so on